# Swift UI Scroll View - How to limit the height to screen height

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, swift5

I am using `SwiftUI` `UIScrollView`. Right now when user drag the screen above the screen height, some white space will appear and the same when user keep scrolling by the end of the screen content.

I am wondering if there’s any way to fix the `UIScrollView` so that the user cannot keep dragging once they reached the end of the screen content or cannot exceed the screen content height?

Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: I assume you mean `ScrollView` not `UIScrollView`. UIKit's `UIScrollView` has [`bounces`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619420-bounces), but the SwiftUI counterpart `ScrollView` does not seem to have this property (yet).